# Click button is working on one site but its not working on other site

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css, sql

I have a script with me used for manual surfing of sites.
it works like this.
A link is shortened using any URL shortener website. and both original and shortened links are saved in db.
User clicks the visit button, a url shortened link is opened, then after pressing the skip add button user has to copy/paste the shown url in the text box and he presses confirm.
IF the enteries match in the db, then i will credit the user.

The problem that I am facing is, it works fine for some sites and does not work on other sites. using the same script.All the sites have same coding structure. [I install it on Paid to click websites ]

The Problem:
I click visit button [ it works fine ]
after i copy/paste and press confirm button [ it does not work ]

I keep on pressing the confirm button, it simple does not do any thing.

the same code works totally fine with some sites.
Below is the code that i am using ...

```
 <?

    $sql2=$Db1->query("SELECT * FROM tablename");
    while($temp=$Db1->fetch_array($sql2)) {

        {
        $linksHTML .= '<div class="smartbox" id="'.$temp['id'].'" style="height: 300px; width: 270px; background: #F3F4F4; border: 5px solid #36A6CB; border-radius: 12px; float: left; position: relative; padding: 6px; margin: 8px 8px 0 0;">
        <center>
        <div class="title"> <a style="color:blue;"> <b> '.$temp['title'].' </b></a> [ Click Visit, Press Skip Add,Paste URL below and press confirm ] </div>
        <div><font color="green">Cash: <b>$'.$temp['credits'].'</b></font></div>
        <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>

        <div><input class="button" value="Visit" style="background: #409940; border-radius: 10px;" type="button" onclick="window.open(\''.$temp['shorten'].'\');"></div>

        <br>

        <form>
        <b>Enter URL :</b>
        <input name="link_'.$temp['id'].'" id="link_'.$temp['id'].'" size="16" maxlength="150" value="http://" type="text">
        <br><br>
        <input id="btn_'.$temp['id'].'" value="Confirm" style="background: #409940; border-radius: 10px; color: white;" type="button" onclick="validaLink(\''.$temp['id'].'\');">
        </form>

        <br>
        </center>
    </div>';
        }
    } 
} else { echo "No Links "; }
$includes[content]='<div id="msg_link" style="text-align:center"></div>
<div id="tbl" style="width: 850px; margin: 0 auto">
    '.$linksHTML.'
</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
<script>
function validaLink(id)
{
    $.post(\'checkLink.php?'.$url_variables.'\', {id: id, enlace: $(\'#link_\'+id).val(), sid: \''.$_SESSION['sessid'].'\', sid2: \''.$_SESSION['sessid2'].'\', siduid: \''.$_SESSION['sessiduid'].'\'}, function(data){
        if( data == "ok" ) {
            $(\'#\'+id).fadeOut();
            $(\'#msg_link\').html(\'We added the credits to your account.\');
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
} 
</script>
';

?>
```

This script is not developed by me .. I don't have contact with the original developer.

Kindly support

Comment: Okey .. you said it does nothing.. but it must alert or show okey message.. so it simply means AJAX is not working.. Why?? Well i think you Have not inserted Jquery Library. . Is it???

Comment: @reenleedr, As i mentioned in the post ,, that it works fine for some sites but not for others. well for  Jquery Library, I have not idea about jquery. That why i asked in this forum. I have installed in on one other site and it works fine . Kindly suggest.

Comment: $.post() is a jquery function which is used in validaLink() so jquery must be on your site..

Comment: @reenleedr, by adding the library to the non woring sites, its working now.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this in head of your html

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```